# Used rp-pppoe to get the server to use radius for authentication, but pppd is still use eap？

Tags: radius, pppoe

I used the kernel mode of rp-pppoe, configured the ppp option, and added the PPP option

```
Plugins/usr/lib/PPPD 2.4.7 / radius. So
radius-config-file /etc/ppp/radius/radiusclient.conf
```

But my server's syslog looks like this when I use the client call NAME.
here is the syslog

```
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppoe-server[14976]: Session 2 created for client 00:0c:29:1e:42:96 (192.168.1.2) on ens33 using Service-Name ''
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/radius.so loaded.
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Plugin /etc/ppp/plugins/radius.so loaded.
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1708506936.4189] manager: (ppp0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/213)
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/22
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1708506936.4291] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Feb 21 01:15:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1708506936.4291] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppd[14976]: EAP: unauthenticated peer name "test"
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Can't open eap-tls secret file /etc/ppp/eaptls-server: No such file or directory
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppd[14976]: EAP-TLS: Cannot get secret/password for client "test", server "ubuntu"
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Connection terminated.
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <error> [1708506939.4170] platform-linux: do-change-link[214]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <warn>  [1708506939.4170] device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1708506939.4201] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppoe[14978]: read (asyncReadFromPPP): Session 2: Input/output error
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppd[14976]: Exit.
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppoe-server[14813]: Session 2 closed for client 00:0c:29:1e:42:96 (192.168.1.2) on ens33
Feb 21 01:15:39 ubuntu pppoe-server[14813]: Sent PADT
```

I do not know whether pppd is using eap authentication or radius authentication, and I do not know how to check

I tried everything, my radius.so and radiusclient.conf were extracted from external package ppp, I don't know why I can't get the pppoe server to use freeradius for authentication